# Where is the custom symbol key binding/ combination file located for Word 2010 (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

Using Microsoft Word 2010, if you click on the Insert Symbol (Ω), you can create custom key bindings/ combinations to insert certain characters into your Word document. For example, I wanted to be able to insert Ō (an "O" with a macron above it). So, I created the combination `ALT + SHIFT + O`.

I have about two dozen of these combinations that I use on occasion. When I re-format my HD, I have to re-do these combinations when I re-install MS Office.

So, my question is, where would these custom key combinations be stored (file location) so I can save it in the future?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Normal.dotm` file is the default settings file for `Word 2010.` You'll find the file located in a location similar to the following:

> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

**TIP:** You can type `%AppData%` in Windows Explorer to quickly navigate to the AppData/Roaming folder.

When you re-install Microsoft Office you can simply copy this file into the `Templates` folder and replace the existing file.